# Hosting a page with Facebook login within an Iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

Is there a way to display the FB login :

> `https://www.facebook.com/login.phpskip_api_login=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fclient_id%3D199667856843796%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FShoppingCart%252FLogin%252FExternalLoginCallback%253F__provider__%253Dfacebook%2526__sid__%253Dc750cc60beac497fbad2dfd340921f7e%26scope%3Demail%26from_login%3D1&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FShoppingCart%2FLogin%2FExternalLoginCallbac...`

in an IFrame?

I am using the MVC 4  OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient for FB login and the page is hosted in an iframe

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to display the FB login […] in an IFrame?

No, there isn’t (apart from calling the FB.login method of the JS SDK creating an onverlay inside a canvas/page tab app) – for obvious security reasons:

Inside an iframe, I could easily copy Facebook’s login dialog, but send all user input (their Facebook username and password, if I can convince them they need to login first) to my own server.

So that this kind of “phishing” can not easily occur, it is mandatory for the user to be able to see `https://www.facebook.com/…` in the address bar of their browser whenever they login to Facebook – and therefor, since an iframe does not show its documents address anywhere, calling the Facebook Auth dialog within an iframe is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try open new window for facebook login and then return to your iframe